# what does this form value mean?

Tags: php, html, forms, wordpress

I know this is an easy one.... but

I am learning PHP right now and I want to know what the value `"<?php _e('Pay for order', 'jigoshop'); ?>"` means in this form.

```
<input type="submit" class="button-alt" name="pay" id="place_order" value="<?php _e('Pay for order', 'jigoshop'); ?>" />
```

Thanks

Comment: With all due respect, I think you should spend a little amount of time stepping through the tutorial in the PHP manual.  Once you've done that, you should know what `<?php ?>` means, and then infer what the rest of it is.

Comment: are you using a framework or CMS? it looks as if you are using wordpress when i googled for '_e()'

Comment: @OliCharlesworth definitely should and will do that. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<?php _e('Pay for order', 'jigoshop'); ?>" />` is a function call which will return a value that will show in the input box.  This looks like a wordpress function but could be something else as well.  Please tag the question as WordPress as well so you get a more relevant answer.

Here is a wordpress forum which explains the `_e` function: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/ltphp-_emystringvalue-sandbox-gt

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you're using WordPress. In that case, [`_e`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_e) is a function that echos out a translated string, based on the language that a user decides to use. If you want to read more about translating WordPress, read [WordPress's own article about translation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress).

Answer (score 1):

`_e()` is a function of WordPress to echo text.

In this case

```
value="<?php _e('Pay for order','jigoshop'); ?> "
```

will translate into

```
value="Pay for order"
```

It seems to have no sense at all, but using `_e()` provides translation capabilities to all the strings echoed with that function.

Answer (score 0):

`_e()` is a funtion related to localization of text related to localization (also known as translation) in Wordpress.

```
<input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Pay for order', 'jigoshop'); ?>">
```

in the above case `'Pay for order'` is the value that gets echo'ed for domain `jigoshop`.

Comment: you can find more about translation in https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/#Localization_Technology and about _e() in https://wordpress.org/support/topic/ltphp-_emystringvalue-sandbox-gt